# lock the selected rows until update operation

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.3

Can I lock a particular selected rows until updates are done.

we have written query for selecting the rows from Java (CrudRepository) and process them and then update

Issue is:- If two request comes and I have 2 rows available for the requested criteria, then currently same row is selected by select query for both the requests. our expectation is to select different rows rather than selecting the same.

Comment: `select .. for update nowait`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried with this.. but same issue.. getting same records in two different select query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name FYI I am using this with Limit

Comment: if you want to process only one row per request, then `select. . . limit 1 for update skip locked`.  If you tested this with `nowait`, then one request should have grabbed the row and the other should have thrown an error.  Are you sure the requests each have its own transaction?  The row locks are released on `commit/rollback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `SELECT` to lock the selected rows, and you don't want two concurrent queries to select the same rows, use this:

```
SELECT ... FROM atable
WHERE ...
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

Then the first query will fetch and select all rows that meet the `WHERE` condition, while the second query will see nothing.

Two comments:

1. You need to use a transaction that contains both the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`, because locks are released at transaction end.
2. You can add a `LIMIT` clause to the `SELECT` to select and lock a certain maximum of rows.